# how can i make vertical submenu container position same for all categories

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

i have a problem in vertical sub menu container position... how can i make  vertical sub menu container position same for all categories here is my website link is that uses css and java script for this purpose [RDS](http://www.webolaxy.com/rds)

and i want my vertical sub menu container position something like this... [Snapdeal](http://www.snapdeal.com/) which is coming from top for all categories.

here is my html for navigation

```
    <div class="left_panel">
                <div class="box">
                    <h3>See all Categories</h3>
                    <div id="display_menu">
                        <ul id="verticalmenu" class="glossymenu padding">
                          <li><a href="#">4 Camera Systems</a>
                            <ul>
                                <li>
                                    <ol>
                                        <li><a href="#"><img src="images/cctv.jpg" /></a></li>
                                        <li><a href="product_detail.html">8 Camera Systems</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#">8 Camera Systems</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#">8 Camera Systems</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#">8 Camera Systems</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#">8 Camera Systems</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#">8 Camera Systems</a></li>
                                    </ol>
                                    <ol>
                                        <li><a href="#"><img src="images/cctv.jpg" /></a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#">8 Camera Systems</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#">8 Camera Systems</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#">8 Camera Systems</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#">8 Camera Systems</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#">8 Camera Systems</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#">8 Camera Systems</a></li>
                                    </ol>
                                    <ol>
                                        <li><a href="#"><img src="images/cctv.jpg" /></a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#">8 Camera Systems</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#">8 Camera Systems</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#">8 Camera Systems</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#">8 Camera Systems</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#">8 Camera Systems</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#">8 Camera Systems</a></li>
                                    </ol>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                          </li>
                          <li><a href="#">8 Camera Systems</a>
                            <ul>
                                <li>
                                    <ol>
                                        <li><a href="#"><img src="images/cctv.jpg" /></a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#">8 Camera Systems</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#">8 Camera Systems</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#">8 Camera Systems</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#">8 Camera Systems</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#">8 Camera Systems</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#">8 Camera Systems</a></li>
                                    </ol>
                                    <ol>
                                        <li><a href="#"><img src="images/cctv.jpg" /></a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#">8 Camera Systems</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#">8 Camera Systems</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#">8 Camera Systems</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#">8 Camera Systems</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#">8 Camera Systems</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#">8 Camera Systems</a></li>
                                    </ol>
                                    <ol>
                                        <li><a href="#"><img src="images/cctv.jpg" /></a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#">8 Camera Systems</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#">8 Camera Systems</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#">8 Camera Systems</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#">8 Camera Systems</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#">8 Camera Systems</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#">8 Camera Systems</a></li>
                                    </ol>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                          </li>
                          <li><a href="#">16 Camera Systems</a></li>
                          <li><a href="#">All Camera Systems</a></li>
`enter code here`                          <li><a href="#">Dummy Cameras</a></li>
                          <li><a href="#">Lenses</a></li>
                      </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="box" style="margin-top:10px;">
                    <h3>Quick Links</h3>
                    <div class="quick-links">
                        <ul>
                            <li>
                                <a href="#">
                                    <img src="images/hot-icon.png" />
                                    <strong>Hot Products</strong>
                                    <p>Purchase Today's hot product. To view detail click here...</p>
                                </a>
                                <div style="clear:both;"></div>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="#">
                                    <img src="images/special-icon.png" />
                                    <strong>Special Offers</strong>
                                    <p>We offer our customers special packages for CCTV Cameras. Click to view detail.</p>
                                </a>
                                <div style="clear:both;"></div>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="#">
                                    <img src="images/seasonal_offer_icon.jpg" />
                                    <strong>Seasonal Offers</strong>
                                    <p>We offer our customers special packages for CCTV Cameras. Click to view detail.</p>
                                </a>
                                <div style="clear:both;"></div>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="#">
                                    <img src="images/download-icon.jpg" />
                                    <strong>Download Brouchure</strong>
                                    <p>We offer our customers special packages for CCTV Cameras. Click to view detail.</p>
                                </a>
                                <div style="clear:both;"></div>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

here is my javascript

```
var menuids=new Array("verticalmenu") 
var submenuoffset=-2

function createcssmenu(){
for (var i=0; i<menuids.length; i++){
  var ultags=document.getElementById(menuids[i]).getElementsByTagName("ul")
    for (var t=0; t<ultags.length; t++){
    var spanref=document.createElement("span")
        spanref.className="arrowdiv"
        spanref.innerHTML="&nbsp;&nbsp;"
        ultags[t].parentNode.getElementsByTagName("a")[0].appendChild(spanref)
    ultags[t].parentNode.onmouseover=function(){
    this.getElementsByTagName("ul")[0].style.left=this.parentNode.offsetWidth+submenuoffset+"px"
    this.getElementsByTagName("ul")[0].style.display="block"
    }
    ultags[t].parentNode.onmouseout=function(){
    this.getElementsByTagName("ul")[0].style.display="none"
    }
    }
  }
}


if (window.addEventListener)
window.addEventListener("load", createcssmenu, false)
else if (window.attachEvent)
window.attachEvent("onload", createcssmenu)
```

and here is my css style

```
.left_panel
{
    width:230px;
    height:auto;
    float:left;
    margin:10px 0px 0px 10px;
}
left_panel .box
{
    width:230px;
    height:auto;
    float:left;
}
.left_panel .box h3
{
    font-weight:normal;
    display:block;
    background:url(../images/box_heading_bg.png) repeat-x;
    color:#fff;
    padding:5px 0px;
    text-align:center;
    border-radius:5px 5px 0px 0px;
}
#display_menu
{
  box-shadow: 0 1px 8px rgba(0,0,0,0.27);
  border-radius: 0 0 5px 5px;
}
#display_menu ul li
{
    list-style:none;
    padding:2px 0px 2px 25px;
    border-bottom:1px dotted #999;
}
#display_menu ul li ul
{
    margin-left:3px;
    border-top:1px solid #ccc;
    border-left:1px solid #ccc;
    border-bottom:1px solid #ccc;
    border-right:1px solid #ccc;
    border-radius:0px 5px 5px 0;
}
#display_menu ul li ul li
{
    margin:0px;
    padding:10px;
    border:none;
}
#display_menu ul li ul li ol
{
    width:225px;
    float:left;
    margin:0px 10px 20px 0;
    padding-right:10px;
    border-right:1px solid #ccc;
}
#display_menu ul li ul li ol li
{
    padding:5px 0px 5px 0px;
    text-align:center;
    border-bottom:1px dotted #ccc;
}
#display_menu ul li a
{
    text-decoration:none;
    color:#666666;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 600;
    display:block;
    background:url(../images/arrow.jpg) no-repeat scroll 179px 5px transparent
}
#display_menu ul li a:hover
{
    color:#024888;
    background: url(../images/arrow.jpg) no-repeat scroll 179px -30px transparent;
    font-weight: bold;
}


.glossymenu, .glossymenu li ul{
list-style-type: none;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
width:230px; /*WIDTH OF MAIN MENU ITEMS*/
}

.glossymenu li{
position: relative;
}


.glossymenu li ul{ /*SUB MENU STYLE*/
position: absolute;
width:760px; /*WIDTH OF SUB MENU ITEMS*/
background:#fff;
left: 0;
float:left;
top: 0;
display: none;
box-shadow: 0 1px 8px rgba(0,0,0,0.27);
}
.glossymenu li ul a
{
width: 180px; /*WIDTH OF SUB MENU ITEMS - 10px padding-left for A elements */
}

.glossymenu .arrowdiv{
position: absolute;
right: 2px;
background: transparent url(arrow.gif) no-repeat center right;
}

.glossymenu li a:visited, .glossymenu li a:active{
color: #000;
}

.glossymenu li a:hover{
background-image: url(glossyback2.gif);
}

/* Holly Hack for IE \*/
* html .glossymenu li { float: left; height: 1%; }
* html .glossymenu li a { height: 1%; }
/* End */
```

Comment: something like that http://jsfiddle.net/MTT72/, added css for #verticalmenu li:hover ul and bit of javascript

Answer (score 1):

Hope this will help you.

```
ultags[t].parentNode.onmouseover = function () {
  this.getElementsByTagName("ul")[0].style.left = this.parentNode.offsetWidth + submenuoffset + "px";
  this.getElementsByTagName("ul")[0].style.display = "block";
  this.getElementsByTagName("ul")[0].style.position = "absolute";
  this.getElementsByTagName("ul")[0].style.top = this.parentNode.offsetTop - this.offsetTop + "px";
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use position absolute on the hidden div line this:

```
 <div class="box"> 
    <div style="position:absolute; display:none;">your hidden box</div> 
 </div> `
```